# PHP UNIX TIME STAMP

Tags: php, sql

I have a date calendar in my php form which gives me date '19-05-2014'. I should compare this date to database time-modified (1400481271) exactly.

When converted '19-05-2014' to UNIX TIME STAMP, but I get the result as 1397858400 which was a wrong time stamp.

```
            id   userid      timemodified
            370     23          1400481271  
            329     24          1427771915
            333     30          1428309816
            332     32          1428303307
            327     33          1427689703
            328     34          1427710711

   <?php 
     if ( preg_match('/^(?P<day>\d+)[-\/](?P<month>\d+)[-\/](?P<year>\d+)$/', '19-05-2014', $matches) )
     {
       $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, ( $matches['month'] - 1 ), $matches['day'], $matches['year']);
       echo $timestamp;
 }
?>
```

Comment: What is the question here exactly?

Comment: You removed everything..

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misunderstood what you were asking.

Comment: Please read the question exactly.

Comment: Whatever we convert the time stamp should match the database value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date you are trying to match is, converted to timestamp:

```
1400457600
```

If you got a different value you converted it wrong (maybe switched day and month or something similar).

It is, however, while close, still not identical to the given value `1400481271` in your database. 
The reason for this becomes clear if you convert it back to a readable date:

```
05/19/2014 @ 6:34am (UTC) 1400481271
```

For comparison, the given date:

```
05/19/2014 @ 12:00am (UTC) 1400457600
```

As you can see there is a difference because it's the same date, but a different time.

The easiest way would be to retrieve only the date portion from the database.

You can do this in your SQL query like this:

```
SELECT DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( timemodified ) ) AS modified
```

This will return `2014-05-19`, which you can easily compare with your string.

Or, if you can even retrieve it in the same format you get it, so you don't need to rewrite your date with regex:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( timemodified ), '%d-%m-%Y' ) AS modified
```

This will return `19-05-2014` for `1400481271`.

Comment: Thank You very much Gerald Schneider. It was a good explanation.